# I'm trying to implement a click event on a bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have a bootstrap dropdown menu that is auto filled from a database. I am trying to get an event to happen when I click on one of the items in the menu. I have tried

```
$("body").on("click", ".ddBtnClick", function(event) { 
    console.log("Is it working? Yes!!");
});
```

with ".ddBtnClick" being a class assigned to each of the items in the list. but nothing happened.
Here is the code to populate the list from a database.

```
$.getJSON("http://jeremiah.abrahamott.com/DadsCarsObjects.txt", function(data){
    $.each(data.aaData, function(i, option){
    $("#dropdownfill").append($('<li/>').append($('<a/>').attr("id", option.Year).attr("href", "#").attr("tabindex", "-1").addClass("ddBntClick").text(option.Make)))
    });
});
```

Here is the html for the dropdown.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:50px;">
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-  toggle="dropdown" href="#">Make
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" id="dropdownfill">

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with your className. You are registering the delegated event handler for `ddBtnClick` but actual class name is `ddBntClick`.

```
$("body").on("click", ".ddBtnClick", function(event) { 
    console.log("Is it working? Yes!!");
});
```

and

```
.addClass("ddBntClick");
```

Change the class name during construction or change in your event delegation.

```
$(function()
{
    $("body").on("click", ".ddBntClick", function(event) {  
        console.log("Is it working? Yes!!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Great glad it helped out resolving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your Javascript in the `document.ready` event?

```
$(function()
{
    $("body").on("click", ".ddBtnClick", function(event) {  
        console.log("Is it working? Yes!!");
    });
});
```

See the jQuery [`.ready()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for more information and examples.

Also, you should register the click event on the actual button and use `.click()` instead of `.on()`:

```
$(function()
{
    $(".ddBtnClick").click(function(event) {  
        console.log("Is it working? Yes!!");
    });
});
```

Also, you have a **typo**:

```
.addClass("ddBntClick")
```

Should be:

```
.addClass("ddBtnClick")
```